# How to Display Div When Checkbox Is Checked

Tags: python, html, django

I want to display the hidden div when the checkbox is selected. Currently, when the checkbox is selected, the div remains hidden. Perhaps the nested structure of the divs is causing issues?

page.html

```
                <div class="field">
                    <label class="label">Opportunity Information:</label>
                    <div class="field">
                        <div class="control">
                            <label class="checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="ware_type" id="ware_type" onchange="showHiddenField()">Hardware/Software:</a>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <div class="field">
                            <input class="input" name="estimate_id" id="estimate_id" type="text" placeholder="Estimate ID" style="display: none;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

script.js

```
    function showHiddenField(currentObject) {
        var inputDiv = $(currentObject).parent().next();
        if ($(currentObject).is(":checked")) {
            $(inputDiv).toggle('show');
        }
        else {
            $(inputDiv).hide();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where do you think `currentObject` is coming from?

Comment: Plus, if you intended it to be the checkbox, the parent is the label; you'd need `parent().parent().parent().next()`.

Comment: Plus plus, the div isn't hidden anyway, the input is; so it would have to be `parent().parent().parent().next().find('input')`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman what should currentObject be then? The checkbox id?

Answer (score 0):

You could change

```
<input type="checkbox" name="ware_type" id="ware_type" onchange="showHiddenField()">Hardware/Software:</a>
```

to :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="ware_type" id="ware_type" onchange="showHiddenField(this,'#estimate_id')">Hardware/Software:
```

and your javascript (you have jquery)

```
function showHiddenField(e,t) {
  $(t).toggle($(e).is(":checked"));
}
```